# How to combine line by line dictionary into one?

Tags: python, dictionary

I currently have a line by line dictionary:

```
{'file1': 'txt'}
{'mydocument': 'pdf'}
{'file2': 'txt'}
{'archive.tar': 'gz'}
```

Is there a way to turn this into a one line dictionary? The outcome I would like:

```
{'file1': 'txt', 'mydocument': 'pdf', 'file2': 'txt', 'archive.tar': 'gz'}
```

I'm new to Python and a little lost how to do it to a dictionary.

Comment: Is that your "line by line" dictionary a list?

Comment: Do you have a file with the dictionaries? Or are these dictionaries stored in a list?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I originally had a file with the file names on each line and I turned them into the dictionary I have put here. My problem is that they are still on different lines and I don't know how to combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, here is version that reads lines from a file and converts them to one dictionary:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

out = {}
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if not line:
            continue
        for k, v in literal_eval(line).items():
            out[k] = v

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{'file1': 'txt', 'mydocument': 'pdf', 'file2': 'txt', 'archive.tar': 'gz'}
```

Answer (score 2):

There probably is much more "pythonic" way to do this. But this should work.

```
listofdicts = [{'file1': 'txt'}, {'mydocument': 'pdf'}, {'file2': 'txt'}, {'archive.tar': 'gz'}]

combined = {}

for x in listofdicts:
    for y in x.keys():
        combined[y] = x[y]
```

There is nested loops because you cannot call dict.keys()[0]

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = [{'file1': 'txt'},
{'mydocument': 'pdf'},
{'file2': 'txt'},
{'archive.tar': 'gz'}]
allInDict = {}
for i in range(len(d1)):
    k = d1[i].items()
    k = list(k)
    allInDict[k[0][0]] = k[0][1]
print(allInDict)
```